# Evaluating an integral

Tags: integration

I have problem to evaluate the following integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2\phi\, d\phi}{a+b \cos{\phi}}$$
In fact I calculate it using complex integration methods, by changing the variable :
$$z=e^{i \phi} \to I=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(\frac{1}{2i}(z-\frac{1}{z}))^2 }{a+\frac{b}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})}\frac{dz}{iz}$$

And then I proceed by using the calculus of residues and what I find is:
$$ I=\frac{2\pi a}{b^2}-\Theta(|a|-|b|)\mathrm{Sgn}(a)\frac{2\pi}{b}\sqrt{(\frac{a}{b})^2-1}$$

But the article which I'm studying it says that:
$$I =\frac{2\pi a}{b^2}-\mathrm{Sgn}(a-b)\frac{2\pi}{b}\sqrt{(\frac{a}{b})^2-1}$$

What I'm missing?

Comment: In the article, are they only calculating the real part? Because if $|b|>|a|$ then the second term is imaginary (assuming $a$ and $b$ to be real). Or is there some assumption about $a$ and $b$ making the $\Theta$-function obsolete?

Comment: @Clever Now they haven't mentioned any thing about real and imaginary parts. And the only assumption about $a$ and $b$ is that they are real.

Comment: in the result given by the article the integral is obviously wrong whener $a<b$ and $a>0$. so your result is correct